# Incomplete Form Submission Not Being Flagged

Tags: php, forms

I'm having some problems with a form created by a previous developer.  When the user fills out our form it's not alerting the user to incomplete required fields and just redirects the user to the "Thank you" page.  The form is not being delivered because of the missing required fields.

Can anyone tell by the code what it's supposed to do when required fields are missing?  Ideally, I'd like it to highlight the fields that are missing so the user can enter the required information.  If it was never designed to do that in the first place, I'd like it to deliver the message whether there's missing information or not while I figure out the code necessary to make it highlight the missing fields.

Problem code:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "eileenw@ourdomain.com";
$email_subject = "Quiz";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "<p>We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.</p> ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "<p>Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br /></p>";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$address = $_POST['address']; // not required
$city = $_POST['city']; // not required
$state = $_POST['state']; // not required
$vehicleyear = $_POST['vehicleyear']; // not required
$vehiclemake = $_POST['vehiclemake']; // not required
$vehiclemodel = $_POST['vehiclemodel']; // not required
$purchase_or_lease = $_POST['purchase_or_lease']; // not required
$deliverydate = $_POST['deliverydate']; // not required
$mileage_at_delivery = $_POST['mileage_at_delivery']; // not required
$current_mileage = $_POST['current_mileage']; // not required
$seller = $_POST['seller']; // not required
$citystate = $_POST['citystate']; // not required
$Bank_Finance = $_POST['Bank_Finance']; // not required
$dealer_arranged = $_POST['dealer_arranged']; // not required
$employee_discount = $_POST['employee_discount']; // not required
$warranty = $_POST['warranty']; // not required
$length_contract = $_POST['length_contract']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
$email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
$email_message .= "Vehicle Year: ".clean_string($vehicleyear)."\n";
$email_message .= "Make: ".clean_string($vehiclemake)."\n";
$email_message .= "Model: ".clean_string($vehiclemodel)."\n";
$email_message .= "Purchase or Lease: ".clean_string($purchase_or_lease)."\n";
$email_message .= "Delivery date: ".clean_string($deliverydate)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mileage at Delivery: ".clean_string($mileage_at_delivery)."\n";
$email_message .= "Current Mileage: ".clean_string($current_mileage)."\n";
$email_message .= "Selling Dealer: ".clean_string($seller)."\n";
$email_message .= "Seller City and State: ".clean_string($citystate)."\n";
$email_message .= "Bank or Finance Company: ".clean_string($Bank_Finance)."\n";
$email_message .= "Dealer Arranged: ".clean_string($dealer_arranged)."\n";
$email_message .= "Employee Discount? ".clean_string($employee_discount)."\n";
$email_message .= "Warranty: ".clean_string($warranty)."\n";
$email_message .= "Contract Terms: ".clean_string($length_contract)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: info@ourdomain.com' . "\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add the `required` field to your html input tag. This will alert the user that the field needs to be filled in when the submit button is clicked.

Here is an example

```
<form action="form.php">
  FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That worked.  Problem is, it's set up to redirect to the home page if required fields are missing.  I think I'll start fresh with a new form that will highlight the missing fields so they can be corrected by the user.  What do I need to modify to keep it from checking for missing fields (so we can get the emails even if they're incomplete) while I create a new form?  Thanks,  Kevin G

Comment: @Kevin98 - Please can you tick the answer if it was correct. If I was you, a workaround for now, would be to create a blank string for every missing field that is passed to the script?

Comment: Sorry for being so dense but do you mean place a ( "") somewhere in the PHP or HTML code?  If so, where?

Comment: In php, try this - - if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) { $first_name = " ";}

Comment: I'm getting this on line 47 (the line you suggested): "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/user/ourdomain.com/send_quiz_email.php on line 47"  I copied your line verbatim.  Thanks

Comment: I didn't copy the double hyphen.

Comment: Missing bracket, sorry.. Try if(!isset($_POST['first_name'])) { $first_name = " ";}

Answer (score 1):

The form isn't incomplete, because the way you're checking it is wrong. `isset($_POST['foo'])` doesn't look if the field has a value, it just checks if the field was submitted at all.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="" />
```

would submit `foo=`. The key exists, therefore `isset($_POST['foo'])` will be `true`. It'll just have an empty string as its value. You need to check BOTH if the field exists and that it contains something, e.g.

```
if ($_POST['foo'] === '') {
     blank field submitted
} else {
     something got submitted
}
```